# Ref and State difference in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Here i got idea about ref in React JS. But still not clear why  ref is being used instead of State.

Answer (score 1):

Refs are normally used to access DOM elements generally to set or get the html properties such as Width, Height etc. You can also use it to get the value e.g from a text field. States define the properties of a component that can change by different actions you perform.

Comment: Can you please elaborate its importance by any real time problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an example. Suppose you want to integrate Material Design Lite ([MDL](https://getmdl.io)) into your React app. In order to properly hook MDL into a React component, it needs to have direct access to the underlying DOM element. That might be a valid use case for using `refs`.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    window.componentHandler.upgradeElement(this.node);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.componentHandler.downgradeElements(this.node);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button
        ref={node => { this.node = node; }}
        className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  } 

}

export default Button;
```